# select 2 table with same column without join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2016

i have 2 table like this

```
---------tbl1----------------
id  | name   | lname |
1      j          h
2      jj         hh
```

and

```
---------tbl2----------------
_id  | name   | lname |
1        a         b
2        aa        bb
3        aaa       ccc
```

i want to select from this 2 table like this:

```
---------result----------------
resultId   |  id  | name   | lname | 
   1           1      j         h
   2           2      jj        hh  
   3           1      a         b
   4           2      aa        bb
   5           3      aaa       ccc
```

but with select using join the result not this format! what can i do to access this select result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically looking for `union all`:

```
select row_number() over (order by which, id) as resultid,
       id, name, lname
from ((select id, name, lname, 1 as which from tbl1
      ) union all
      (select _id, name, lname, 2 as which from tbl2
      )
     ) n
order by which, id;
```

The only tricky part is the use of `row_number()` to assign the final `resultid`.